# Button on floating footer would not work

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am new to Android and WebDev. I am creating a web app in which i am using jquery mobile. I have a floating footer which has a button on it. But the button would not work until i browse all the way down on the web page which is included in the web-app. This is how i have done it

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-iscroll="scroller">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
            <a href="camera.html" data-role="button" data-icon="gear"> 
            Take Picture ! 
            </a>
    </div>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```